Batch Conversion of MP4 to re-encode audio codec to MP3
I have 100s of MP4 videos that were ripped using using WinX DVD Ripper (Personal use only).  However after I finished them my Samsung TV wouldn't play them without the sound disappearing intermittently.  I changed the audio codec from AAC to MP3 with AVIDemux on one file and it works perfectly. Now I need to batch convert them in silent mode.  I don't need to r-encode the video.  AVIdemux seemed to do it perfectly but most of the batch files I have seen seem to encode the video as well.  Any ideas?

Since there is no mention of Ubuntu in your question it appears to be off topic. Please edit the question with the Ubuntu details.

This has to be done with ffmpeg, and does not depend on the exact Ubuntu version. This is definitely on topic unless explicitly stated by OP.
